# Cordova - show/open Smartphone Keyboard always

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, keyboard

is it possible to show the keyboard on a smartphone always? I have an input text field. But the keyboard will open up just if the user clicks the input field. 
It would be nice if the keyboard stay open. Like on whatsapp. You can send a message and the keyboard will be open.

i tried a plugin like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard#keyboardwillhide

The methode Keyboard.show(); works very well. But just one time. And not every time... 
My idea was something like

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardWillHide', function () {
    Keyboard.show();
});
```

but the methode doesnt work... i dont know why, but noting happens in the body of die keyboardWillHide.

I hope someone has an idea :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can revert an hiding action while it is going to be executed. Try

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardDidHide', function () {
    Keyboard.show();
});
```

but I'd find a way to prevent the autohide